# Fetching all entries from db(Firestore) to a list using a model

Tags: dart, model, flutter, fetch

Trying to fetch a List from firestore using a Model which works without the model but not with it.

In a StatefulWidget I got an empty List of Products. basically comes from the model like this

```
class Product {
  int id;
  String title, price, message;
  Product(this.id, this.title, this.price, this.message);
}
```

The List of Products like this

```
import 'package:presentation_app/models/product.dart';

class _ProductsListState extends State<ProductsList> {

  List<Product> products = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
...
```

then added a `StreamBuilder` with the `firestore` collection like this

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
            return BuildListView(products);
          }
      ),
```

and in the `BuildListView` class I've then called the List of Products and used it like so:

```
class BuildListView extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Product> products;
  BuildListView(this.products);
```

in the `listViewBuilder` I then tried to access the data like so:

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

        int id = products[index].id;
        String title = products[index].title;
        String message = products[index].message.toString();
        String price = products[index].price.toString();
```

I get the `CircularProgressIndicator` but after it finishes loading nothing pops up.

using this approach it works, but of course not with the model

```
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
            return BuildListView(products: snapshot.data.documents);
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BuildListView extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<DocumentSnapshot> products;

  BuildListView({this.products});
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the `model` is not needed, because I was not working with a business logic, so the `model` is obsolete, If using `Bloc` and a db like `firebase` the `bloc` using a `model` should look something like this.

```
  Future<void> createData(docId) {

    final Tracker createTracker = Tracker(
        id: docId,
        comment: _commentController.value,
        exercise: _exerciseController.value,
        number: _numberController.value,
        repetition: _repetitionController.value,
        sets: _setsController.value,
        weight: _weightController.value
    );

    print(_commentController.value + _numberController.value.toString());

    return trackerDb.createData(docId, createTracker);
  }
```

and the db model for creating data something like this for example.

```
  Future createData(String docId, Tracker tracker) async {
    await db.document(docId).setData(convertTrackerToMap(tracker));
  }
```